# DevExpress XtraReport data binding for object attributes

Tags: reporting, devexpress, data-binding

I have an report, in which I like to show reports about some Employees. The Employee Class contains the following attributes :

```
public class Employee {
    public string name;
    public Branch branch;
}
```

I have an list of employees, and I bind them to the report columns. It is showing employee name without any problem in the first column of the report table, but in the second column it is showing the Branch object's assembly, namespace etc etc. (It is obvious, of course, since I am binding the whole Branch object to that column).

My question is : how can I show employee name in one column and corresponding branch name in another column?

My Branch Class has the following definition :

```
 public class Branch{
                  public int branchId;
                  public string name;
 }
```

I am adding an data source to the report class from the tool box, creating an `XtraReport` object, and simply assigning an Employee list as follows :

```
XtraReport1.DataSource = EmployeeList;
```

Comment: What are you binding the report to? an xpcollection with the employee as the object data source?

Comment: @SnOrfus: I have edited my question and added my binding code

Comment: Well, I have got an temporary solution. I have added a new property named "BranchName" which returns "this.branch.name" from the Employee class. But I think this is not a good one. Can someone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XtraReport objects can do sub-property binding.  Give your label the text "[branch.name]" (rather than picking the data source with the designer drop-down).

Comment: they call it "mailmerge" https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument2433 and allows to put some fields between text on labels and report controls

Answer (score 1):

your binding probably looks like:

```
....DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", employee, "branch"));
```

change it to

```
....DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", employee.branch, "name"));
```